# Запуск функции input

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, туплю сегодня по серьезному... Спасайте ситуацию :D
Есть скрипт, надо запускать его по окончанию выбора фото, без всяких последующих кликов, типа как [тут первый вариант](https://fineuploader.com/demos.html). Думаю тут не чего особо объяснять, что да как, обычный загрузчик файлов на сервер через Ajax

```
<script>

    var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    alert(form_data);
    $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function(php_script_response){
                    alert(php_script_response);
                }
     });

</script>



<input id="sortpicture" type="file" name="sortpic" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в чем вопрос?

```
jQuery(dcoument).ready(function ($) {

    $('#sortpicture').on('change', function (event) {
        var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        alert(form_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(php_script_response){
                alert(php_script_response);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Нет, не хочет выполнять функцию. Может это из-за того, что это input?

Comment: засуньте этот код после подключения jQuery

Comment: Спасибо, ещё правка небольшая dcoument -> document